# How to copy sets of paragraphs from word to excel?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a list of data that is too long for excel to open - when I try to open it, I get a message saying it can only open files with 65000 rows or so, and it suggests using word to split them up.  I am attempting to make a macro that:

1) split this data up into sets of 65000

2) paste each set into a worksheet so that excel can use it

What I have so far:

```
Sub divider()

Dim dt1 As Document
Dim oex As Excel.Application
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim savepath As String
Dim cutrange As Variant
Set oex = New Excel.Application
oex.Visible = True
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add
While wb1.Sheets.Count <> 1
    wb1.Sheets(2).Delete
Wend
Set dt1 = ThisDocument

If dt1.Paragraphs.Count > 65000 Then
    Set cutrange = dt1.Range(dt1.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, dt1.Paragraphs(65000).Range.End)
    If wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        wb1.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets.Count
    End If
    cutrange.Cut Destination:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Cells(1, 1)
    wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
Else
    Set cutrange = dt1.Content
    If wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        wb1.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets.Count
    End If
    cutrange.Cut Destination:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
    wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
End If

End Sub
```

(Just..imagine for now that there are more parameters for the texttocolumns)

Right now my specific struggle is that on the line `cutrange.Cut Destination:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)` it returns an error "Run Time Error 448: Named argument not found".  I am not sure what in there is unnamed.  I tried turning `wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)` into `wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count))`, but that just gave me "Run Time Error 13: Type mismatch", which I also don't see what is mismatched.

More generally, I don't *really* understand how vba works with word.  It's much easier for me to understand with discrete cells...which word does not have.  Is this the right approach?

Bonus problem: I opened one set of this data, and with 19.2 million words in the data, it eventually reached too many pages and word said it could open no more.  Is there a way to make word split this data up before the sheet dies?

Edit: I just found out about the shell command when I hunted around some more.  I don't know how to assign the resulting application/sheet to oex/wb1 so that I can refer to it in the code.  I have this instead of what is above:

```
Sub divider()

Dim dt1 As Document
Dim oex As Excel.Application
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim savepath As String
Dim cutrange As Variant

AppActivate (Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL", vbNormalNoFocus))
Set oex = GetObject(class:="Excel.Application")
oex.Visible = True
Set wb1 = oex.ActiveWorkbook
```

Unfortunately, even having Excel 2010 already open does not change the fact that this still sets oex equal to Excel 2003 (I also tried setting `oex=shell(path)` but that didn't fly).  What the hell, Microsoft?  How do I set oex to Excel 2010 or wb1 to just directly reference the workbook I opened?

Comment: Which version of Office are you running? Is Excel running in .xls compatibility mode?

Comment: I am running Word 2010; both 2010 and 2003 are installed on the computer.  I *think* it opens up excel by default in 2003 - is there a way to make it open up the newer version?  Is that advantageous?  How would I go about doing that?  (And how do I check if it is in compatibility mode?)

Comment: The title bar says `(Compatibility mode)`. In Excel 97-2003 format (and therefore in compatibility mode), the maximum number of rows is 65,535 and 256 columns. In Excel 2007-2016 the maximum is 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns. IMO you seriously need to consider what you're using Excel for if you have that much data. Excel isn't a database engine.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to open in 2010?  For that matter, why would Word 2010 automatically open Excel 2003, instead of the same generation version?  (or is there a program that would be more suited for this sort of thing, if that's the better solution?)

Comment: If you open a .xls in Excel 2007+ it will open in compatibility mode. Save a copy as .xlsx (.xlsm if it has macros) and if you need to open a .xlsx/.xlsm in Excel 97-2003 you need to download an add-in that allows you to do that.

Comment: I'm confused - I want to open up a new document, not an old one.  Or is the only way to get it to open up excel 2010 to save a sheet from the default (2003) in 2010 format, close it, then immediately open it up again?  Seems like kind of an oversight on Microsoft's part, in that case...

Comment: I'm not sure which part is unclear - .xls is the old file format, if you open it in Excel 2007+ Excel will be in "compatibility mode" and apply Excel 97-2003 restrictions *until the workbook is closed*, so yeah once you save it in .xlsx/.xlsm format you have to reopen it to dismiss the compatibility mode.

Comment: Okay.  I just don't understand why there's no way to open up a new type of workbook of the correct type from the very start.  Open, save, close, reload seems circuitous.  Also, did more hunting online and found out about the shell command.  Is that more efficient?  If so, I figured out how to use it to open up the right version of excel, but how since it returns a number, how do I assign the resulting application/workbook to oex/wb1?

Comment: So I tried to open it using a regular ol' `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\users\GPerry\desktop\opentest.xlsm")`.  This still opened up in Excel 2003.  Even though .xlsm is specifically made for later versions of Excel and 2003 should be unable to open it?  Why does this application overrule *everything*?

Comment: Was Excel/Office 2003 installed *after* 2010? Verify your file associations. That's a Windows problem, not Excel.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it seems to have been. So it uses the most recent one?  Damn.  Thanks for the help, though.  Really feels like Microsoft should add the ability to pick which one you open it with...